# Changing tree (folder) icon conditionally

Tags: extjs

I want to change the folder icon on tree conditionally only for a certain type of task and not all.
The tasks that are displayed on the left side on name column.
By default it is displaying a closed folder if a leaf else an open folder.
I have a field that checks for type of node.It can be activity/ticket/subticket.

For ticket I want to change the icon.
I tried following code but the issue is , it displays the new icon but the older one is not replaced/removed.They both are displayed.

```
{
                    xtype: 'namecolumn',
                 //   tdCls: 'namecell',
                    width: 200,
                    renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
                        if(record.get('IsTicket'))
                        {
                           meta.tdCls = 'isticket';
                        }
                       return value;
 }
```

and then in css

```
.isticket {
    background-position:center  !important;
    width: auto !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("images/delete.gif") !important; 
}
```

Furthermore , I am trying this on Bryntum's Gantt , asked on the their forum but they say its more of extJs related.

Answer (score 0):

You need update your CSS to

```
.isticket .x-tree-icon{
    background-image: url("images/delete.gif") !important; 
}
```

Alternatively, If you have control on json data, you can define the iconCls as part of data.

Here is the fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/174b